# Python dice game using list

Tags: python

i'm trying to develop a python dice game run as a sequence of dice values starting from 1. starting from 1 is valued at 3 points. If there is no 1 the hand is 0 and a hand of dice can contain more than one run.

For example [5,6,2,4,2,3,6,4] is 0

[3,4,1,5,3,1,4,6] is 6 (two 1)

[2,1,1,1,2,3,3,2] is 24 (two 1,2,3 = 18 and one 1,2 = 6)

[5,3,2,6,4,5,1,4] is 18 (one 1,2,3,4,5,6)

```
def get_hand_score(list_of_dice):
   score1 = 0
   list1_sorted = list_of_dice.sort()
   if "1" in str(list_of_dice):
      score1+=3
      if "2" in str(list_of_dice):
        score1+=3
        if "3" in str(list_of_dice):
          score1+=3
          if "4" in str(list_of_dice):
             score1+=3
             if "5" in str(list_of_dice):
               score1+=3
               if "6" in str(list_of_dice):
                 score1+=3

return score1


def test_get_hand_score():
   print("1.  score: ", get_hand_score([5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3]))
   print("2.  score: ", get_hand_score([3, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6]))
   print("3.  score: ", get_hand_score([5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1, 4]))
   print("4.  score: ", get_hand_score([2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2])) 
   print("5.  score: ", get_hand_score([3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6]))

   list1 = [5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3]
   print("6.  dice: ", list1)
   score1 = get_hand_score(list1)   
   list1.sort()
   print("    dice_sorted: ", list1)
   print("    score:", score1)
   print()

   list1 = [5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1, 4]
   print("7.  dice: ", list1)
   list1_sorted = sorted(list1)
   score1 = get_hand_score(list1)
   print("    dice_sorted: ", list1_sorted)
   print("    score:", score1)
   print()

   list1 = [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]     
   print("8.  dice: ", list1)
   list1_sorted = sorted(list1)
   score1 = get_hand_score(list1)
   print("    dice_sorted: ", list1_sorted)
   print("    score:", score1)
   print()
```

which gave me:

```
1. score:  0
2. score:  3
3. score:  18
4. score:  9
5. score:  18
6.  dice:  [5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3]
    dice_sorted:  [2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
    score: 0

7.  dice:  [5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1, 4]
    dice_sorted:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
    score: 18

8.  dice:  [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
    dice_sorted:  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
    score: 9
```

expected result:

```
1. score:  0
2. score:  6
3. score:  18
4. score:  24
5. score:  21
6.  dice:  [5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3]
    dice_sorted:  [2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
    score: 0

7.  dice:  [5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1, 4]
    dice_sorted:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
    score: 18

8.  dice:  [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
    dice_sorted:  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
    score: 24
```

Comment: There isn't exactly a question here, but for starters your `if "1" in str(list_of_dice)` doesn't *count* the number of ones, it just adds 3 to the score if there's a 1.  Basically what you've got now just does 3 times the length of the longest possible sequence starting at one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works (produces your expected output):

```
from collections import Counter

def get_hand_score(dice):
    counts = Counter(dice)

    total = 0

    while counts[1] > 0:
        n = 1
        while counts[n] > 0:
            counts[n] -= 1
            total += 1
            n += 1

    return total * 3
```

The problem with your code is that you only ever count one sequence. You look for a 1 and then a 2, etc., but you don't mark those in any way as "used" and then repeat. So when your code sees 123123, it just counts 123 once.

**EDIT**

Simpler (maybe?) working code:

```
def get_hand_score(dice):
    counts = Counter(dice)

    n = counts[1]
    score = 0

    for i in range(1, 7):
        n = min(n, counts[i])
        score += n

    return score * 3
```

The idea here is that every 1 found increases the score. (At a minimum, it's part of a sequence of just 1.)

After that, every 2 up to the number of 1s increases the score. And every 3 up to the number of 2s we counted increases the score again.